# Registering a new instance of SQL Server 2005 without affecting the current instance

Tags: sql-server-2005

I need to register a few different instances of SQL Server on a machine that is already running a default instance.  Is there way to do this without affecting the default instance?  I read that I need to run through the install process again to do this, but it seems like there has to be a better/easier way.  Anybody know?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add new instances of a SQL Server you must run the installation again. Always. There is no 'easier' process to add a new instance, nor to change the name of an existing one.

Each instanc eis independend, so new instances won't affect the existing instance. When you start the installation you will be prompted for the name of the new instance.

Comment: Correct. You can install a new instance of SQL Server and it will not interfere with your default instance. You can even install a different version of SQL Server (2008 R2 for example), and assuming all the pre-requisites are in place you'll be fine.

Comment: Interesting... thanks for the info.  Do you know if I need the installation media, or can I just click on CHANGE in Add/Remove Programs?  Also, can I use my Developer Edition CD to install a Developer Edition instance alongside an Enterprise Edition instance?

Comment: You need the install media.  The beautiful thing about multiple instances is that you can run completely different versions/patch levels/editions side-by-side without the instances impacting each other.  MSDN discovers instances here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa174516%28SQL.80%29.aspx (that's for SQL Server 2000, but the concepts apply).  A table with the versions of SQL server that can live side-by-side is here (it depends on the CPU architecture): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143694.aspx

Answer (score -2):

Are you sure u need to run the install process for registering a DB instance?

afaik - You just provide the instance name, port, uid/pwd and register it.

Comment: And how do you go about registering this new instance? The only way I know is to run the setup program and select the option to install a new, named instance as 
Remus has stated.

Comment: You absolutally 10000000000% need to run the installation process to register a new instance. Otherwise what are you connecting to? Take it from someone who's been doing it for years! This way you can mix SQL versions and flavours.

Comment: just tried on a test box, u were right. Thanks farseeker